# Unknown provider in angularJS with angular-cached-resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have properly added a JS file for angular-cached-resource (https://github.com/goodeggs/angular-cached-resource) in  my angular app, and is trying to instantatiate it:

```
angular.module('client.core.resources')
.factory('TranslationResource', ['$cachedResource', 'ConstantValueService', function ($cachedResource, ConstantValueService) {
    var localizationUrl = ConstantValueService.get('webApiUri') + '/api/localization/';


    // TODO adjust webapi to work.
    return $cachedResource('translationResource', localizationUrl, {lang: '@lang'},
        {
            getTranslationForCulture: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true
            },

        });
}]);
```

but I am getting Error:

> [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cachedResourceProvider <-
>   $cachedResource <- TranslationResource <- TranslationService error.

What I could be getting wrong?

Comment: Have you included the `angular-cached-resource.js` file in your HTML?

Comment: can you setup a plunker...

Comment: Have you included `ngCachedResource` as a dependency in you rmodule declaration?

Comment: YEs, that @PSL suggestion was totally right. Doc misses that part. PSL, can you make an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @AskarIbragimov Sure added as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$cachedResource` service is a part of `ngCachedResource` module and hence in order to use it you need to list `ngCachedResource` as a dependency in your app.

```
 angular.module('myApp',[...,'ngCachedResource'])....
```